# how to use state for choosing multi image uri from react-native image-picker?

Tags: react-native, use-state

I am currently developing uploading photos through using react-native-picker

(launchImageLibrary)

When I bring a picture through useState,

```js
const [images, setImages] = useState({});

const showImage = async () => {
  await launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
    if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log("User cancelled image picker");
    } else if (response.error) {
      console.log("ImagePicker Error: ", response.error);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
      console.log("User tapped custom button: ", response.customButton);
    } else {
      let results = [];
      response.assets.map((imageInfo) => results.push(imageInfo.uri));
      if (response.assets.length > 1) {
        // multi images. ***it doesn't work!!!***
        setImages([...results, ...images]);
      } else {
        //image only 1  **it works!**
        setImages(...results);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

in return

```js
//Yes It works for only one
<Image source={{ uri: images }} style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }} />;

//It doesn't work for multi images
{
  images > 1 &&
    images.map((image, idx) => (
      <Image
        key={idx}
        style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }}
        source={{ uri: image }}
      />
    ));
}
```

JSON.value error occurs when I upload a lot of pictures.

I think this problem lies in dealing with objects, but I can't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan't to support multiple images  you should make a list like this

`[{uri:'...'},{uri:'...'}, etc...]`

So change your useState to be this

```js
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

And your showImage function to be this

```js
const showImage = async () => {
        await launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            } else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
            } else {
                let results = [];
                response.assets.forEach(imageInfo => results.push(imageInfo.uri));
                if (response.assets.length > 1) {
                    // multi images. ***it doesn't work!!!***
                    setImages([...results, ...images]); // a list
                } else {
                    //image only 1  **it works!**
                    setImages(results); // a list 
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Then do this below to show the images

```js
//It doesn't work for multi images
 {images.length !==0 &&  images.map((image, idx) => (
   <Image key={idx} style={{width: 150, height: 150}} source={{uri: image}} />
 ))}
```

Comment: Thanks
in your answer, I change source={{uri: image}}.
image.uri it doens't show image on screen
Thanks again!